# error: ‘class std::map’ has no member named ‘first’

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered-map

I was trying to count the frequency of all elements of an array using map. Here is the code that I was trying-

```
void count(int arr[] , int n){
    map<int ,int> d;
    for(int i=0;i<n ;i++){
        d[arr[i]]++;
    }
    for(auto i : d){
       cout<<d.first<<" "<<d.second<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Basically I was using map to store the frequencies of elements of array and I tried it on C++14 , but it gives the following error-
**error: ‘class std::map’ has no member named ‘first’**

I think the map has first and second member inbuilt in it, then Why it is giving the error??
If there are any corrections in the code , please let me know

Comment: where is the `unorderd_map`

Answer (score 1):

[`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) does not have a member function called `first`. Did you mean [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) which is the `value_type` of an `std::map` and provides access to the key-value pairs?

Answer (score 1):

The `first` and `second` fields are in the elements of the map (which are of type `pair`), not in the map itself.

```
    for(auto i : d){
       cout<<i.first<<" "<<i.second<<"\n";
    }
```